# Getting an error on Android when reading the image from expo-camera and expo-image-manipulator

Tags: react-native, image-processing, expo, base64, expo-camera

**Image manipulator package: expo-image-manipulator**
**Camera package: expo-camera**

✅Camera is working and file is created.
✅Manipulator is working and file is created.
❌When converting compressed photo to base64 format i am getting this error:

Error: Location 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImageManipulator/55bc375d-a4f9-4a5f-b041-2dbaccd654ca.jpg' isn't readable.

```
// Take photo
    let photo = await camera.takePictureAsync()
    // Set image
    setImage(photo.uri)
    const uri = photo.uri
    const width = photo.width
    const height = photo.height

    // Process Photo
    // Resize photo
      const compressedPhoto = await manipulateAsync(uri, [{ resize: { width: width, height: height } }], {
        compress: 0.3,
        format: SaveFormat.JPEG,
      })
      // Convert to base64
      const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(compressedPhoto.uri, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
      })
      // Set file
      setFileForAWS(new Buffer.from(base64, "base64"))
      // Set file name OS + User ID + Date
      setFileNameForAWS(`${Platform.OS}-${user._id}-${Date.now()}.jpg`)
```